# Extracting year and month from datekey in my sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a datekey column in my database. I want to extract Year and Month from it.

```
Datekey column
20140101
20151223
20140809
20201201
```

Comment: You want us to provide a solution based on this?? Please add datekey datatype.

Comment: Dates in a database should be stored as `DATE`. If your date key is a number or a string instead, I recommend you change this. If it is a `DATE`, as it should be, use the date functions `YEAR` and `MONTH` or `EXTRACT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
select month(convert(datekey,char)) as mon, 
       year(convert(datekey,char)) as yr
from tablename
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these are numbers, use numeric operations:

```
select floor(datekey / 10000) as year,
       (datekey / 100) % 100 as month,
       datekey % 100 as day
```